# HorizontalScrollView Siempre a la derecha despues de agregarle texto Android APP

Tags: android-studio

Una pequeña consulta me gustaria saber como es posible que un HorizontalScrollView que voy llenando con texto se mantenga siempre a la derecha cosa que se vea el ultimo texto ingresado, estoy haciendo una calculadora tipo la de windows 10. La applicacion la estoy desarrollando en android studio y hasta el momento tengo esto

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/ScrollCalculadoraHistorial"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtCalculadoraHistorial"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:text=""
            android:textSize="30sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

y en el activity uso esto pero no me funcional del 100% `ScrollCalculadoraHistorial.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_RIGHT);`
ya que se mueve a la derecha pero no al final de esta

Answer (score 0):

podrias pobrar con esto :D

He modificado el XML, espero que te funcione :D.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<HorizontalScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtCalculadoraHistorial"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|end"
            android:text=""
            android:textSize="30sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```